# How do I make a multiproject gradle build in STS eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, gradle, spring-tool-suite, multi-project

I have 2 separate projects in STS Eclipse, both using gradle to build. One is a web application. The other is a data access library that the web application uses. I have the buildship plugin for this.

Normally, I would simply change the project properties to include the data project in the web application's build path/project references/etc to make this work, but we're switching over to using Gradle for this.

I have a working build.gradle file in each project, but I don't know how to make the web app's build script build and include the data project.

I've looked for various tutorials and examples, and they talk about a root project that contains both projects inside. I have no idea how to create this.

How do I go about setting this up?

Furthermore, I'm concerned about SVN in a setup like this. I want to be able to commit each project separately since other applications will use the data access library, which is why it's a separate project. My understanding is that a nested project structure suggested by gradle would cause the entire root project to be committed as 1 entry, with both subprojects.

This would then mean that I would have to copy the data access project into all the other projects that need to use it, which would make maintaining the code a pain. At that point, I might as well not have a separate data access project and instead just include all that code in a package in the web app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was the "includeflat" command in the settings.gradle